# Error with Object Attributes in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute

I'm getting an error when setting an Attribute with either custom or standard object in Lightning Component.

**Component Code**

```
<aura:attribute name="acc" type="Account" access="global" />
```

Below is the error message,

[image]

The error disappears as soon as removing the Attributes. Any idea what's wrong here? Thanks...!

Comment: 1.Are the field API names correct? javascript is case sensitive, you need to match exactly. Try removing one by one and isolate the issue

Comment: Yes, the API names are correct. I removed the custom object and still getting the error even only with Account object.

Comment: @Sudh: Could you edit your post to include component code with any standard object. Tried with Account object, works fine.

Comment: P.S. it's `sobjectType`, not `SObjectType`. This may be causing the problem.

Comment: @Raul: I removed the custom object and keep the standard object, Account, as the above code. But still, I'm receiving the error.

Comment: @sfdcfox: I removed the default value and custom object as above. But still, the error is persisting.